# DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to group the table by a column and get the counts, then create dictionary using the result. The last statement returns the error of

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.

What the error means?

```
var a = context.Table;
var b = a.GroupBy(x => x.RecordType, (k, cnt) => new { RecType = k, cnt = k.Count() });
var c = b.Select(x => 
    new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<Type, int>>(
        x.RecType, Tuple.Create(ObjTypes[x.RecType], x.cnt)))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GroupBy` call is slightly wrong - it's ignoring the `cnt` parameter. It should be written like this:

```
var b = a.GroupBy(x => x.RecordType, (k, cnt) => new { RecType = k, cnt = cnt.Count() });
```

That exception message is one of the more unhelpful I've seen. The problem is that when you call `Count` on `RecordType` (aliased as `k`) in the C# expression it compiles fine, because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. Unfortunately, when EF tries to convert that expression to SQL it needs to be able to use the SQL `count` operator, which can't work on a `string` - it needs to operate over a sequence of rows. This results in the somewhat cryptic exception you received.

Incidentally, the query assigned to `c` won't work either - `Tuple.Create` can't be translated into SQL, nor can `ObjTypes[x.RecType]`. You'll need to call `ToList` on variable `b` before you can do all that additional shaping of your results.

Comment: And this is why we use meaningful variable names for parameters, even for lambdas.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 The construction of the `KeyValuePair` isn't in a supported manor.  Just remove the `Select` entirely and do the projection in the `ToDictionary` call.

Comment: @Servy, good suggestion, that's more efficient than calling `ToList`.

Comment: You should basically never use `ToList` if you're just going to call another LINQ method on that list.  It's eagerly evaluating the query, creating a list, and populating it all entirely needlessly.  The only reason to use `ToList` would be when a query is entirely finished and eager materialization is important.